# Is there a way to fix the issue of Vscode freezing up in few seconds or minutes after its opened

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I have been going back and forth searching why and how to fix this particular problem regarding `Vscode` freezing up my whole working space including the `host`, when I am in the middle of working on a project or immediately I open it. Preventing me from finishing up my projects. I am using `Linux` on `VirtualBox`. Is there an actual way I can `fix` this problem? I know there have been other developers facing similar issues, but I have not being able to find a clear answer to solving this problem still.

Answer (score 5):

VS Code by default searches the many thousands of files in `node_modules` or other similar directories.

You can prevent this behavior by simple edit your `settings.json` file paste this code.

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
    "**/.hg/store/**": true
  }
```

Comment: Will this inadvertently cause other, undesirable side-effects? What exactly is this doing?

Answer (score 2):

Some things to try:

- Disable all your extensions. There are some extensions which might not play nicely with VirtualBox
- Disable settings sync
- Do a complete reinstall VSCode

If these fail, I would take some steps to verify that it is in fact VSCode that is causing your workspace to freeze.

Comment: Where do I navigate to, in order to disable the extensions?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20quickly,until%20you%20re%2Denable%20them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when updating the VM. This is what I did.

Solution 1:
VirtualBox: Re-install VBoxWindowsAdditions. Make sure to overwrite existing configurations during reinstallation.

VMware Player: Re-install VMware Tools. Make sure to overwrite existing configurations during reinstallation.

Solution 2:
Uninstall VBox or VMware Player completely, use an advanced uninstaller that removes all associated registry entries. After uninstalling, consider reinstalling VBox or VMware Player. Start with the latest version, and if you still encounter issues, you can try downgrading to a previous version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).